# New array from Multiple foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array out of three arrays in the following manner:

```
    $file_data = array();

    foreach($file_ids as $key => $id){
       foreach($file_names as $name_key => $name){
          foreach($file_amounts as $file_key => $cost){
             $file_data[] = array("id" => $id, "filename" => $name, "amount" => $cost);
             break;
         }
         break;
      }

   }
```

It's creating the first row only. How can I get it to properly assign the values to the $file_data array?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
As an example, I have the following for the three arrays

```
    $file_ids[0] = 2;
    $file_ids[1] = 4;

    $file_name[0] = name1;
    $file_name[1] = name2;

    $file_amount[0] = 10;
    $file_amount[1] = 9;
```

These arrays will always be of the same size.

What I would like to do is iterate over these arrays and end up with a final array of the form:

```
$final_array = (id, name, amount)
```

for all rows in other arrays.

Comment: give us example original array and result array.

Comment: Well... you have several breaks there, which imply to stop looping, and therefire PHP will process the first elements of your nested arrays only. But you are not saying what you want to accomplish (what did you expect to get).

Comment: get rid of the breaks... your're saying "create first row" then breaking twice to exit the loops

Comment: If I take the break's off, then the final array will end up with many more rows than the original arrays.

Comment: So you want an array, $file_Array, to contain rows of information. Each row consists of an array like this, array(id, name, amount)? Thus to get the id if the second row item you would say $file_Array[1]['id']. Am i understanding the question correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These arrays will always be of the same size.

Just loop to the width of either array:

```
$final_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($file_name); $i++)
{
    $final_array[] = array($file_ids[$i],$file_name[$i],$file_amount[$i]);
}
```

Comment: haha, I knew I was making it more complicated than necessary. I changed the index to $i=1, and also <= (the way the arrays were built in my case) and it's working wonderfully now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `array_map` and `array_combine`:

```
$file_ids = array(2, 4);
$file_name = array('name1', 'name2');
$file_amount = array(10, 9);

$result = array_map(null, $file_ids, $file_name, $file_amount);

$keys = array('id', 'filename', 'ammount');
$result = array_map(function($el) use ($keys) {
    return array_combine($keys, $el);
}, $result);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [filename] => name1
            [ammount] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [filename] => name2
            [ammount] => 9
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Only iterate over one array

```
$file_ids = array(2,4);
$file_name = array('name1', 'name2');
$file_amount = array(10,9);

$cnt = count($file_ids);

$file_data = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++){
    $file_data[] = array('id' => $file_ids[$i],
                     'filename' => $file_name[$i],
                     'amount' => $file_amount[$i]);
}

var_dump($file_data);
```